# Hibernate map enum to varchar

Tags: hibernate, enums, hibernate-mapping, varchar

Suppose I have this enum:

```
public enum TestEnum { EXAMPLE, FURTHER_EXAMPLE, LAST_EXAMPLE }
```

With this mapping in the `.hbm`:

```
<property name="testEnum" column="TEST_COLUMN">
    <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
        <param name="enumClass">p.a.c.k.TestEnum</param>
    </type>
 </property>
```

The enum is sent to the database as `0`, `1`, `2`. I'd like the values to be instead stored as `EXAMPLE`, `FURTHER_EXAMPLE` or `LAST_EXAMPLE` in a varchar column.

How can I map enum to a varchar column?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896666/adding-an-enum-as-a-class-property-in-hbm

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add this as a parameter of EnumType:

```
<param name="type">12</param>
```

This is because `12` is equivalent to [java.sql.Types.VARCHAR](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.sql.Types.VARCHAR)

Comment: 12 is equivalent to java.sql.Types.VARCHAR.

Comment: I saw that value while browsing for solutions, but thought it was a default value for the enum. It's not very descriptive, looks like a magic value. Thank you!

Answer (score 16):

Maybe this is more descriptive

```
<param name="useNamed">true</param>
```

Comment: `useNamed` is there in hibernate since 4.2.0.Final where as `type` is there even in 3.1beta9
 [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.2.0.Final/org/hibernate/type/EnumType.java/)
 [link](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.hibernate/hibernate-annotations/3.1beta9/org/hibernate/type/EnumType.java/)

Answer (score 5):

You can use annotations like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    TestEnum testEnum;
    @column(name="TEST_COLUMN")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public TestEnum getTestEnum(){
        this.testEnum;
    }
}
```

Comment: The question was for hbm mapping, not annotation.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to store any enum's value as varchar in database, please follow below steps.

1. Hibernate provides an UserTpe interface. We need to create a class which implements UserType interface.

   ```
   import java.io.Serializable;
   import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
   import java.sql.ResultSet;
   import java.sql.SQLException;
   import java.sql.Types;

   import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
   import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;

   public class EnumUserType<E extends Enum<E>> implements UserType {
      private Class<E> clazz = null;

      protected EnumUserType(Class<E> c) {
          this.clazz = c;
      }

      private static final int[] SQL_TYPES = { Types.VARCHAR };

      public int[] sqlTypes() {
              return SQL_TYPES;
      }

      public Class returnedClass() {
          return clazz;
      }

      public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet, String[] names, Object owner)
           throws HibernateException, SQLException {

          String name = resultSet.getString(names[0]);

          E result = null;
          if (!resultSet.wasNull()) {
              result = Enum.valueOf(clazz, name);

          }
          return result;
      }

      public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, Object value,
           int index) throws HibernateException, SQLException {

          if (null == value) {
              preparedStatement.setNull(index, Types.VARCHAR);
          } else {
              preparedStatement.setString(index, ((Enum) value).name());
          }
      }

      public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
          return value;
      }

      public boolean isMutable() {
          return false;
      }

      public Object assemble(Serializable cached,Object owner) throws HibernateException {
          return cached;
      }

      public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
          return (Serializable) value;
      }

      public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner)
           throws HibernateException {
          return original;
      }

      public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
          return x.hashCode();
      }

      public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
          if (x == y)
              return true;
          if (null == x || null == y)
              return false;
          return x.equals(y);
      }
   }
   ```
2. Suppose I have a EncryptionStatus Enum.

   ```
   import java.io.Serializable;
   import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable;

   public enum EncryptionStatus implements IsSerializable, Serializable {
       PLAIN, HASH, RE_HASH, SUPER_HASH, SUPER_REHASH, OPEN, ENCRYPT, RE_ENCRYPT
   }
   ```
3. We need to create a class which extends our created EnumUserType>.

   ```
   public class EncryptionStatusType extends EnumUserType<EncryptionStatus>{

      public  EncryptionStatusType() {     
          super(EncryptionStatus.class);
      }
   }
   ```
4. Now we need to map above created class in hbm.xml file in stead of Enum mapping which store enum value as varchar in the database. For Example,

`<property name="secureStatus" type="com.nextenders.facadeimplementation.util.userenum.EncryptionStatusType"
        column="secure_status" />`