# java.sql.SQLException: Data truncated for column

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, enums

I'm new in Java programming. I have an enum data type in my class:

```java
public class Persons {
    private String name;
    private String family;
    private Date birthDate;
    public enum degree {Bsd, Msd, prof};
    private degree degree;
    ...
}
```

In my MySQL database, I have a field for degree as: `ENUM('Bsd','Mds','prof')` and my hibernate mapping is like this:

```xml
<class name="Entity.Professor" table="tbl_professor">
     <id column="ProfessorId" name="ProfessorId"/>
     <property column="name" name="name"/>
     <property column="family" name="family"/>
     <property column="birthDate" name="birthDate"/>
     <property column="degree" name="degree"/>
</class>
```

When I want to insert a new record in my table, I get this error:

```
Hibernate: insert into tbl_professor (name, family, birthDate, degree, ProfessorId) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Apr 26, 2013 6:15:24 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
WARNING: SQL Error: 1265, SQLState: 01000
Apr 26, 2013 6:15:24 PM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
SEVERE: Data truncated for column 'degree' at row 1
Apr 26, 2013 6:15:24 PM org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener performExecutions
SEVERE: Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
    at DAO.ProfessorDAO.createProfessor(ProfessorDAO.java:21)
    at Entity.Test.main(Test.java:39)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Data truncated for column 'degree' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:2028)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1451)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:246)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Data truncated for column 'degree' at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2427)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1980)
    ... 12 more

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:141)
```

Can anyone help me? I'm really confused with `enum` datatype.

Answer (score 8):

Data truncation is when you add records that are longer than the maximum column size of the database column (in your case `degree`).

Since your MySQL ENUM for DEGREE column is of 3 types, you can annotation your enum with [`@Enumerated`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Enumerated.html) as follows:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private degree degree;
```

- More info on [`EnumType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EnumType.html).

Answer (score 2):

You need to map enums differently in hibernate, Hibernate provides org.hibernate.type.EnumType to map Enumerated types

```
   <property name="degree">
      <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
         <param name="enumClass">pkg.degree</param>
      </type>
   </property>
```

If you want the string to be stored instead of index 1,2 etc, you need to use
      12

12 - java.sql.Types.VARCHAR

see the link 
  [Hibernate map enum to varchar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839553/hibernate-map-enum-to-varchar)

Comment: my enum type is not a seprate class, so it seems that i do not need to use param.... my database field is :degree ENUM('Bsd','Mds','prof')

Answer (score 1):

Well you're getting a Data truncation error, so I would check to see the allowed length of your MySQL column. Generally you'll see this error if the data in that field is either larger than your Hibernate/JPA mapping, or the length of the allowed db column.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be not to use enum type of mysql. An alternative is plain String or even better an extra table with an id as relation.

It has several disadvantages. The major one being maintaining it. You can't easily change the order or remove something in there

If you google for mysql this page is 3rd for a reason: http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/