# org.hsqldb.HsqlException: data exception: invalid character value for cast

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, hsqldb

I have a table in an HSQL database which has an identity(integer) column.  I'd like to support querying against the column using an arbitrary string(potentially non-numeric).  However, the HSQL JDBC driver tries to cast the query parameter to an integer and throws an exception.  The Oracle driver seems to support this case fine.

Any ideas to alter this behavior in the hsql driver?

org.hsqldb:hsqldb:2.3.0

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table(id IDENTITY NOT NULL);
```

The query:

```
final String query = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id=?";

String id = "abc";
jdbcTemplate.query(query, new PreparedStatementSetter() {
    @Override
    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
        ps.setString(1, id);
    }
}, someMapper);
```

The exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id=?]; data exception: invalid character value for cast; nested exception is java.sql.SQLDataException: data exception: invalid character value for cast
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:605)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:639)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:668)
    .
    .
    .
Caused by: java.sql.SQLDataException: data exception: invalid character value for cast
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.throwError(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.setParameter(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.setString(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setString(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:135)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setString(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:135)
    at com.stackoverflow.SomeDao$2.setValues(SomeDao.java:39)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:644)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:589)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: data exception: invalid character value for cast
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Scanner.convertToNumber(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.types.NumberType.convertToType(Unknown Source)
    ... 40 more
```

Comment: `SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id='abc'` does not make *any* sense. Why would you want to search for characters in a column that is known to not contain any. If you can't convert the user input to a number, you can skip the whole database query and disply "Nothing found" to the user because you *know* there can't be any matches.

Comment: I already mentioned this as a workaround. I'd rather not have do this throughout the various daos. Its to easy to miss a spot

Comment: I still don't understand why you want to do that in the first place. Comparing apples to oranges seems rather pointless. One possible workaround would be to cast the *column* to a character representation: `SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE cast(id as varchar(20)) = 'abc'`. But that would prevent the usage of an index on that column.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem comes from attempting to compare a numeric column to a non-numeric string. The string is attempt converted to a number prior to comparison and causes the cast exception to be thrown if it isn't a number as a string.

Some work arounds:

- Change the String to a long.  This isn't really an option as non-hsql datasources
  need to support arbitrary string ids.
- The dao could check that the String is numeric and only then make the
  query.  This is acceptable, but I was hoping not to have to do this.

Comment: Or change the column to a String :)

Comment: You're right. I've never regretted making an ID colum a string

Answer (score 0):

For me this

Caused by: java.sql.SQLDataException: data exception: invalid character value for cast in statement [select * from x where x.status = 'READY_FOR_WRITE']

meant I was using hibernate and by default it was creating status as an Integer instead of a string for an enum.  [Fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30477111/32453).