# Using JdbcTemplate in Spring Boot

Tags: sql, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, h2

I've generated a Spring Boot web application using Spring Initializer, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

Technologies used:

Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE, Spring 4.3.4.RELEASE, Thymeleaf 2.1.5.RELEASE, Tomcat Embed 8.5.6, Maven 3, Java 8

I have this classes

```
    public class DeviceEvent {


        public DeviceEvent(Device device) {
            this.device = device;
        }

        private Device device;

        private Long id;

        private Double latitude;

        private Double longitude;

        private Date dateReceived;

        private String message;

        private Float rssi;

        private Integer battery;

        private Boolean alarm;

        private Boolean processed;

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public Device getDevice() {
            return device;
        }

        public void setDevice(Device device) {
            this.device = device;
        }

        public Double getLatitude() {
            return latitude;
        }

        public void setLatitude(Double latitude) {
            this.latitude = latitude;
        }

        public Double getLongitude() {
            return longitude;
        }

        public void setLongitude(Double longitude) {
            this.longitude = longitude;
        }

        public Date getDateReceived() {
            return dateReceived;
        }

        public void setDateReceived(Date dateReceived) {
            this.dateReceived = dateReceived;
        }

        public String getMessage() {
            return message;
        }

        public void setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public Float getRssi() {
            return rssi;
        }

        public void setRssi(Float rssi) {
            this.rssi = rssi;
        }

        public Integer getBattery() {
            return battery;
        }

        public void setBattery(Integer battery) {
            this.battery = battery;
        }

        public Boolean getAlarm() {
            return alarm;
        }

        public void setAlarm(Boolean alarm) {
            this.alarm = alarm;
        }

        public Boolean getProcessed() {
            return processed;
        }

        public void setProcessed(Boolean processed) {
            this.processed = processed;
        }
    }


but I got this error executing this test:

    Device device = new Device("C380F");

            DeviceEvent deviceEvent = new DeviceEvent(device);

            deviceEvent.setId(Sequencer.getNextVal());
            deviceEvent.setAlarm(Boolean.FALSE);
            deviceEvent.setBattery(78);
            deviceEvent.setDateReceived(new Date());
            deviceEvent.setLatitude(50.834015);
            deviceEvent.setLongitude(4.377885);
            deviceEvent.setMessage("FAKE_MSG");
            deviceEvent.setProcessed(Boolean.FALSE);
            deviceEvent.setRssi((float)80);

            repository.insert(deviceEvent);


...

@Override
    public long insert(DeviceEvent newDeviceEvent) {

        long id = Sequencer.getNextVal();

        int numOfRowsAffected = jdbcTemplate.update(
                "insert into T_DEVICE_EVENT (ID, DEVICE_ID, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, MESSAGE, DATE_RECEIVED, RSSI, BATTERY, ALARM, PROCESSED) " +
                        " values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);",
                        id,
                        newDeviceEvent.getDevice().getId(),
                        newDeviceEvent.getLatitude(),
                        newDeviceEvent.getLongitude(),
                        newDeviceEvent.getMessage(),
                        newDeviceEvent.getRssi(),
                        newDeviceEvent.getBattery(),
                        newDeviceEvent.getAlarm(),
                        0);

        if (numOfRowsAffected==1) return id;
        else return -1;


    }
```

..

the table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS t_device_event (
    id              bigint PRIMARY KEY,
    device_id       bigint NOT NULL,
    latitude        decimal NULL,
    longitude       decimal NULL,
    message         varchar(100) ,
    date_received   timestamp,
    rssi            float,
    battery         int,
    alarm           boolean,
    processed       boolean,
    FOREIGN KEY (device_id) REFERENCES public.t_device(id));
```

the error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [insert into T_DEVICE_EVENT (ID, DEVICE_ID, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, MESSAGE, DATE_RECEIVED, RSSI, BATTERY, ALARM, PROCESSED)  values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: incompatible data type in conversion
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:91)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:649)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:870)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:931)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:941)
    at com.ideefecloud.iot.repository.JdbcDeviceEventRepository.insert(JdbcDeviceEventRepository.java:44)
    at com.ideefecloud.iot.repository.JdbcDeviceEventRepositoryTests.testInsert(JdbcDeviceEventRepositoryTests.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: incompatible data type in conversion
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.throwError(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.setParameter(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.setObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:454)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:238)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:169)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.doSetValue(ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.setValues(ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.java:47)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:875)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$2.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:870)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: incompatible data type in conversion
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.types.DateTimeType.convertJavaToSQL(Unknown Source)
    ... 44 more
```

Comment: Problem might be in Database table definition. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18842454/org-hsqldb-hsqlexception-data-exception-invalid-character-value-for-cast (btw. possible duplicate)

Comment: you may use localdatetime instead of date deviceEvent.setDateReceived(LocalDateTime.now());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your columns/parameters are misaligned. The `date_received` specifically doesn't seem to have a corresponding parameter so it's trying to convert a `float` (RSSI) into a `timestamp`