# Hibernate, Enum failing to cast to Integer

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have been trying to use an enumerator as a model field that would be saved as an integer in database, but the casting fails in Hibernate. I have installed the hibernate-core and hibernate-jpa-2.1-api maven packages.

I have a Bug.hbm.xml file, where I have set these fields as int

```
        <property name="state" column="State" type="int" />
    <property name="status" column="Status" type="int" />
```

Example model:

```java
package Model;

// Class for the bug-object.

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
public class Bug {
    private int id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private BugState state;
    
    public Bug() {
    }
    
}
```

The enum

```java
package Model;

public enum BugState {
    OPEN, CLOSED
}
```

The error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class Model.BugState cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (Model.BugState is in module com.example.application of loader 'app'; java.lang.Integer is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

Any help would be appreciated since I am new with Java and Hibernate!! It's difficult

Comment: And I am running on jdk 16!

Comment: Why do you have annotations AND a hbm.xml?

Comment: I tried similiar solution as here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6470114/8323418 , but it didnt seem to work either, and I was still getting the same error. I'm not sure if they're mutually exclusive though

Comment: are you trying to do some crud operations in your repository?

Comment: Yes, im trying to insert the item (the bug class here) into a database

Comment: before inserting it into a database try to cast your bug class into an integer

Comment: Ditch the `hbm.xml` file, you only need to annotations. The xml takes precedence over your annotations.

Comment: Is there any reason to prefer annotations over hbm.xml?

Comment: hbm.xml is legacy because there is a orm.xml for that in the JPA standard. But since we have annotations developers prefer annotations because it's closer to the code

Answer (score 0):

Ok so from:

```html
        <property name="state" column="State" type="int">
            <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
                <param name="enumClass">Model.BugState</param>
            </type>
        </property>
        <property name="status" column="Status" type="int">
            <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
                <param name="enumClass">Model.Status</param>
            </type>
        </property>
```

I removed the type="int" from each property, and it started working. I did not realize this overrides the enumType.

Like this

```html
        <property name="state" column="State">
            <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
                <param name="enumClass">Model.BugState</param>
            </type>
        </property>
        <property name="status" column="Status">
            <type name="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">
                <param name="enumClass">Model.Status</param>
            </type>
        </property>
```